# Execute python script on my pc with a button on Android and wait for another button to continue execution

Tags: python, android, ssh

I hope you can help me, my doubt is the following (maybe it is not possible).

How can I run a python script on my pc when I press a button on android (ssh maybe) and that the script is "waiting" for another button to be pressed.

For example. (not code, just logic) in the following order.

°In android°

I press button 1 and it sends to the pc the command to execute (ssh maybe).

°On my pc°

The script is executed, for example

```
print('Button 1 was pressed')

input('waiting...') ### Here it is waiting for button 2

print('Button 2 was pressed')
```

°On android°

Button 2 is pressed and an 'enter' ('\n') is sent to the pc and then the input is fulfilled and the second print appears.

I appreciate your time and comments on this.

I have tried ssh, but apparently the session logs out and I can no longer interact with the same script.

Comment: you need a kind of IPC throught TCP/IP. use socket library. your android is a socket client for an app on your pc. that app will launch( subprocess) your script. That app should receive your command from android and pass them to your script (using, a database, IPC communication, web api etc)

Comment: Alternatively consider how your idea would work as a website. If you can get the website to work, it is relatively simple to transform it into a webservice which the Android app can then connect to and behave similarly.